# libcaffeconverter import error for caffe to onnx

Tags: python, neural-network, caffe, onnx, coremltools

Problem Description

---

I'm following the caffe to onnx tutorial at https://github.com/onnx/onnx-docker/blob/master/onnx-ecosystem/converter_scripts/caffe_coreml_onnx.ipynb and I encounter this error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'libcaffeconverter' from 'coremltools'

On further investigation, I realized that there is no libcaffeconverter in the coremltools directory.

System information

---

OS Platform and Distribution: Windows 10 x64
ONNX version: 1.7.0
Python version: 3.7.7
Protobuf version: 3.13.0
Visual Studio version (if applicable): 2017 version 15.9.28307.1234

Reproduction instructions

---

Create a NEW environment and run "pip install coremltools==4.0b3"

Run the code at https://github.com/onnx/onnx-docker/blob/master/onnx-ecosystem/converter_scripts/caffe_coreml_onnx.ipynb

OR

Run:

import coremltools
coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(None)

Expected behavior

---

I expected the code to create and save a an onnx file based on the caffe file specified in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: switch to python 3.6

like the OP the problem was with `import coremltools coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(None)`, producing `ImportError: cannot import name 'libcaffeconverter'
This can be avoided by using a virtual environment with python 3.6

Workaround:

1. Create a python 3.6 environment with your package manager of choice in the terminal:
   `conda create -n <your env name here>  python=3.6 anaconda`
   OR
   `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6`
2. activate the virtual environment
   `conda activate <your env name here>` (or pip equivalent)
3. navigate to your project directory and run your file
   `python <your script here>.py`

now it should work as planned